# How to declare static variable in a class method that is not shared between all instances of a class?

Tags: c++, class, static

I want the following code to create 2 different i variables or one per instance.

```
class A {
   void foo() {
      static int i = 0;
      i++;
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
   }
}

auto i1 = A();
auto i2 = A();

i1.foo();
i2.foo();
```

I want the output to be:

```
0
0
```

How can I declare a variable that exists only within that function but is persistent between function calls?

If you're curious of the exact reason I need this behavior, it's a bit complicated and not necessary for this question I don't think, but here's what I'm working on:

I'm trying to make a macro for logging that creates a static lambda that throttles the logging output. It is intended to be used within class methods. The current macro looks like this.

```
#define ROS_UTILS_THROTTLE_MACRO(LOG_MACRO, message, duration) do {                                         \
  static auto COMBINE(throttle_log_,__LINE__) = [&](const std::string&& msg, rclcpp::Duration&& period) {   \
    static auto next_log_time = ros2_utils::system_time_now() + period;                                     \
    auto current_time = ros2_utils::system_time_now();                                                      \
    if(current_time >= next_log_time)                                                                       \
    {                                                                                                       \
        LOG_MACRO(message);                                                                                 \
        next_log_time += period;                                                                            \
        if(next_log_time <= current_time)                                                                   \
        {                                                                                                   \
            next_log_time += period;                                                                        \
        }                                                                                                   \
    }                                                                                                       \
  };                                                                                                        \
  COMBINE(throttle_log_,__LINE__)(message, duration);                                                       \
} while (0)
```

Usage of this macro would (roughly) look like this:

```
class A {
   void foo() {
      ROS_UTILS_THROTTLE_MACRO(INFO_LOG, "message", 1s);
   }
}
```

2 instances of A should have 2 different log functions that are both being throttled separately.

Comment: Use a class member variable?

Comment: Is it not possible to just make it a member of `A`? That would give you one per instance, though obviously it would be shared between all functions of `A`. But often there are members of a class that are only used within a couple of functions

Comment: I can't add it as a member variable because I'm trying to write a macro for logging that creates the variable within a function. I need that variable to persist between function calls so that the logging works as intended. The variable that the macro declares is a lambda that keeps track of the last time logged and ensures that the last time logged wasn't within the throttle duration.

Comment: This statement "How can I declare a variable that exists only within that function but is **persistent between function calls**?" contradicts with output you want to see, it is unclear what you want.

Comment: what about a static map of this pointer to int.  Then it would be inside the function and still different per class.  I will make an example.

Comment: You cannot have an instance-specific `static` variable. It appeas that you are facing a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @slava it should be persistent between calls only from that instance. Like a member variable yes, but I want/need to be able to declare it from within the function.

Comment: Then use `std::unordered_map<std::string,int>` as a member and access it using `__func__` as the key.

Comment: @Slava keying the map on `__func__` would not yield per-instance values, though

Comment: @RemyLebeau it would if that map is not a static member - ie separate map per `A` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your macro code, I think the following idea should work.

```
class A {
   void foo() {
      static std::map<A*, int> theMap; // This is the logging specific
                                       // data, unrelated to the data
                                       // of the class.
      theMap[this]++;
      std::cout << theMap[this] << std::endl;
   }
};
```

One of the downsides of the approach is that you will not be able to release memory used by `theMap` until the program exits. If you construct and destruct a lot of instances of `A`, you will notice memory usage go up without a way to release memory corresponding to delete objects.

Thanks @RemyLebeau for pointing this out.

Comment: This approach will leak `map` entries over time, as there is no way to remove each `A*` key when `this` is destroyed after `foo()` is called. You would have to declare the `map` as a class-static or global variable so that the `~A()` destructor can access it

Comment: @RemyLebeau, fully agree.  I  think a class-static variable is out of the question for the OP since they want it to be function-specific.

Comment: If the class needs separate per-instance counters for each method, it can simply declare a separate class-static `map` member for each method to access, while still allowing the destructor to remove `this` from all of the `map`s. This is really the only way to avoid the memory leak when using `this` as the `map` key